# ¿Es posible enviar la contraseña de un pdf en su enlace?

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, navegador-web

He llegado a la necesidad de encontrar el modo de abrir un pdf protegido sin que el usuario que recibe el archivo tenga que digitar la contraseña sino que ésta sea enviada en el mismo archivo o mediante un enlace. No sé si esto sea una locura y no tenga sentido, pero ya que la contraseña es conocida, me gustaría saber si hay algún modo de embeberla en el enlace o enviarsela al navegador al momento de abrir el archivo.
Tengo dos escenarios donde esta funcionalidad es requerida, al abrir el pdf en su correo como archivo adjunto, y al abrirlo mediante un enlace de aws s3.

Gracias :)

Comment: Todo depende del programa que maneja tus PDFs, por ejemplo, Adobe Acrobat te facilita ciertos [parámetros](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) para llamar/abrir un documento. Tu mejor opción sería encontrar/modificar un [visor JS](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-pdf.js-in-a-website) que pueda aceptar como argumento la contraseña de los documentos. De hecho hay unos cuantos [commits](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/1695) que incluyen esta funcionalidad en pdf.js (que está integrado en Mozilla), solo tienes que ver si está inc

Comment: Algo como lo que mega hace con sus descargas, en las cuales puedes enviar la clave en el hash , o colocarla manualmente ?

Comment: Paula, gracias por tus aportaciones, recuerda agregar más datos y lo que has realizado para que no sea una pregunta basada en opiniones o demasiado amplia, revisa [ask], saludos!

Comment: No tengo la menor idea de cómo hacer lo que digo, o si es posible, la idea es simplemente abrir el archivo protegido sin tener que digitar la contraseña, sino enviársela de algún modo. Quisiera tener ideas de personas que tal vez lo hayan hecho.